# how to run parameterised xUnit test cases via xunit.console?

Tags: xunit, xunit.net, test-runner

I need to run my xUnit test cases through command line. I have some test cases as below:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(2)]
[InlineData(4)]
[InlineData(6)]
public void GivenNumberMustBeAnEvenNumber(int val)
{
    Assert.Equal(val%2, 0);
}
```

How can I run above test case with only 4 as the inline data? I passed -method "MyClass.GivenNumberMustBeAnEvenNumber(4)" to xunit.console but it didn't run. I even tried with -method "MyClass.GivenNumberMustBeAnEvenNumber(val: 4)" but no success.

I also have some test cases that take strings in their parameters as below:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("abc")]
[InlineData("xyz")]
public void GivenStringLengthIsAlwaysThree(string val)
{
    Assert.Equal(val.Length, 3);
}
```

How can I run above test case with "xyz" as inline data only.

Please help.

Comment: there is no way to address an individual leg of a Theory in xunit .console (nb there is also no way to do this in the GUI runners either, and in the default mode, the discovery process does not discover the legs individually in the first instance)

Comment: Hi, Mate. I have Visual Studio 2017 and from its TestExplorer window, I can run any leg of a Theory. So I guess there must be some way to do that. I am exploring this. If I find anything, will let you know. If you came to know how to run some specific leg of a theory, could be with any test-runner (not just xunit.console) that supports this through command line parameters, please let me also know that.

Comment: I would not be surprised if NUnit and/or MSTest support running theort legs from the console runner but pretty sure xunit does not - its worth having a quick peek at the source to be sure - I've def seen it asked for but ultimately most people work around rare cases like this by pulling out a separate Fact I guess